# Finding Grid position value from Column and row number

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with 5 fixed columns.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 5));
```

Now if I know the row number, how can I find the position inside the following:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   // do something if this is column 4 and row 6
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Math magic, if you want to do something specific in all the 2nd columns you can do something like:

`if (position % 5 == 2) {...}`

If you want to do something in the 4th column of the 3rd row, you can do something like:

`if (position == (3 * 5) + 4 ) {...}`

I don't know if this is what you are really asking, elaborate a little bit more if It's not.